# Group By Select New Object

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve a list of games from my database and the count the number of games that a specified team won and lost and put it into an object with a win and loss property. I was trying this but it doesn't seem to be correct.

```
var winLoss = _teamService.GetGames()
    .Where(x => x.Result != "Tie")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Result)
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Wins = x.Count(a => a.Result == "Hello"),
        Losses = x.Count(a => a.Result != "Hello") 
    });
```

The return type for this is an `IQueryable` whereas I want it to just be a single object with a Win and Loss property.

Doing a `GroupBy` on the Results would put all the Wins for the current team into one group and then separate groups for each team they lost to in their own separate group.

Comment: Wins are marked "Hello"? You don't seem to be filtering on a specific team in your attempt?

Comment: The Result is just the name of the team that won, In that example the team Im checking for is called "Hello"

Answer (score 0):

Using a LINQ query you're going to end up with a collection, but what you care about is essentially a list of keys and values. I believe this will supply you the information you're looking for:

```
var winLoss = _teamService.GetGames()
    .Where(x => x.Result != "Tie").GroupBy(x => x.Result)
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Count());

int wins = 0;
int losses = 0;
winLoss.TryGetValue("WIN", out wins);
winLoss.TryGetValue("LOSS", out losses);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the wins and losses for each team:

```
var winLoss = _teamService.GetGames()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Team)
    .Where(gg => gg.Key == "Hello")
    .Select(gg => new 
    { 
        Wins = gg.Count(g => g.Result == "Hello"),
        Losses = gg.Count(g => g.Result != "Hello")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went with two simple count calls to the SQL database.

```
Wins = _teamService.GetGames().Count(x => x.Result == "Name");
Loses = _teamService.GetGames().IsNotTie().Count(x => x.Result != "Name");
```

It's not 100% what I wanted but to do it in one call involved more complicated LINQ and therefore more complicated SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Add `FirstOrDefault()` at the end of your **linq** query so you will get only the first element:

```
var winLoss = _teamService.GetGames()
.Where(x => x.Result != "Tie").GroupBy(x => x.Result);

var win =  winLoss.Select(x => x.Count(a => a.Result == "Hello")).FirstOrDefault();
var loose =  winLoss.Select(x => x.Count(a => a.Result != "Hello")).FirstOrDefault();
```